# How can i fix System AggregateException ? in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Yesterday everything was okay but today when i try run my code its giving that error to me : `System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Unable to resolve host "api.lokmanecza.com": No address associated with hostname)'` 
Yesterday it was working with no problem and i didnt changed any code and its giving that error what should i do ?  I tried check google but i cant found any good answer. Please help me. What can i do ? Thanks!

```
            string postUrl = $"http://api.lokmanecza.com/api/GetControlPackageList/1/1";


            var stringContent = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            string json = client.PostAsync(postUrl, stringContent).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;



            List<LoginApiResponseModel> model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoginApiResponseModel>>(json);
            var counter = model.Count;
```

Its my posting json code.

Comment: "unable to resolve host" is a pretty basic DNS error

Comment: Not sure why it would work one day, but not the next, but does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56578868/199364) help?

Comment: Add await `string json =  await client.PostAsync(postUrl, stringContent).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` and check.